# Android: How to save sensor data onSensorChanged to a database?

Tags: android, database, arraylist, dynamic-data, android-sensors

I'm writting an android app in which I'm acquiring the **accelerometer data** from the sensor of the phone **until** the user quits. Afterwards I modify the data and try to save it to an existent database. Everything works fine, but when I'm calling my **saveToDatabase**() method in the **onSensorChanged** method, then the app starts to work extremely slow and becomes unresponsive and crashes shortly after. 
So, the problem is that i'm calling saveToDatabase() **too often**...

Is there a way to avoid that?

- May be with an *ArrayList/LinkedList/ArrayDeque* where the sensor data have to be collected and after 5mins saved to the DB?
- Or put everything in a *Buffer* and when the user exits then extract everything from it to the database?
- Modify the saveToDabase method so that it uses *beginTransaction* instead of the *insert*-method?

  ```
      protected void saveToDatabase(){
           contentValues.put("SensorSensitivity", sensorSensitivity);
           contentValues.put("AccDataX", accelerometerData[0]);
           contentValues.put("AccDataY", accelerometerData[1]);
           contentValues.put("AccDataZ", accelerometerData[2]);
           contentValues.put("timeStamp", System.currentTimeMillis());
           long affectedColumnId = sqliteDatabase.insert("tName", null, contentValues);
           contentValues.clear();
  }
  ```

Comment: call this function from service so that other functionality in application wont get affected

Comment: In addition to what sachin said, I like your idea of saving up a bunch of points and inserting them as a batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android documentation suggest on every place where you work with IO, use different thread for disk manipulation.

I suggest you should use one thread to receive onSensorChanged events, save it to memory, maybe add timestamp and values. Add several such values to array, then use handler or other way to pass this structure to another thread. That thread should save it into database, ie. Loop through all gathered values and save each like your saveToDatabase. This way. UI should be responsive all time, even when long queue waits to be written to disk.

This might work, but there should be some feedback about how fast saving of values is and how big is incoming queue. If it is too long, you might drop some values to prevent full memory. Maybe saving thread would send using handler event to UI thread, that queue is full and it does not want new values for a while. When it reduces queue or make it empty, it would tell UI thread to start sending again.

Comment: thanks guys for the advices :) Now everything works fine.
As you proposed, I made a new thread responsible for the database so that it works along with the MainActivity. I also saved the sensor values in ArrayLists and when they are filled up, I forward them to the separate thread. Then I empty those ArrayLists and begin to fill them again while the saveToDatabase thread runs on his own.